# Borders for integral from a set

Tags: integration

I have a question about the borders of an integral given by a set.

Let $$D:=\{(x, y)  \in \mathbb R^2 : x>0, y\geq 0, x+y\leq 2\}$$

How can I estimate the borders for $x$ and $y$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y$ from $0$ to $2-x$ and $x$ from $0$ to $2$ OR $x$ from $0$ to $2-y$ and $y$ from $0$ to $2$.

Comment: that means $$ \int_0^2 \int_0^(2-x) $$ this integral ?

Comment: Yes, $\int_0^{2}\int_0^{2-x} f(x,y)dydx$.

Comment: Thank you very much!